# What discount rates should I use to price a municipal bond with unknown market price?

Tags: fixed-income, bond, pricing, discount-factor-curve

I have a payoff structure but I do not know the price of the bond. The bond is municipal. What discount rates should I take for each period in order to calculate its fair price?

Answer (score 0):

The standard curve for this is the MMD AAA GO NC Zero curve published by Thomson Reuters. There is likely a Bloomberg equivalent, you can check using AAA

Comment: Would you be willing to buy some Illinois and California munis at this price?

Comment: 90%+ of munis are AAA and AAs price only marginally cheaper to risk free as I'm sure you know. It's an assumption OP isn't asking about IL or a low rated credit. Cals often trade at or through benchmark due to state tax, so if you have some you're selling cheap to MMD give my desk a call and we'll take 'em off your hands...

Comment: Since the OP didn't say what he's asking about, then I think your answer would be even better if you mentioned for completeness that some munis do have higher yields. Assuming that he _didn't_ mean City of Chicago can lead to oops moments :)  (But we can probably safely assume he meant **U.S.** munis and not e.g. provinces of Argentina or Russian oblasts.)

Comment: Given that the question/answer was over 2 years ago with no follow-up this is just splitting hairs...